# PyCrypto install by copying 'lib' folder on Windows7 64bit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

I'm trying to install PyCrypto 2.4.1 on my local machine (Windows 7 64bit).
But, I got following messages on 'python setup.py install'.

> running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> running build_ext
>
> warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
>
> building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
>
> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

What I want to ask is this: can I just copy `lib` folder which contains `Crypto` folder in it to where my app is located? I'm developing a Google AppEngine app using Python27 runtime, and, I just need local library for PyCrypto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I just needed some compiled version of PyCrypto for Windows 64bit.

- PyCrypto version: 2.3.1
- Python version: 2.7.1
- Target platform: Windows 64bit

And, I could get one from [here](http://yorickdowne.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/compiling-pycrypto-on-win7-64/). And, [this](http://archive.warshaft.com/pycrypto-2.3.1.win7x64-py2.7x64.7z) is a direct download link.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Did a bit of research for you, and here's the bug that was filed for the SDK:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2493

Summary of the issue:
GAE has a customized version of PyCrypto 2.0.1 installed. Docs can be found [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#PyCrypto).

SDK does not include the PyCrypto implementation from GAE, so it needs to be installed locally. However, the default path for installation is blocked by the SDK. Solution recommended in the bug comments is to install PyCrypto in each app's directory. Steps are outlined in the bug comments (not trivial).

Hope this helps!

EDIT: This one could be helpful as well: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1627

Comment: Well this answer is actually incorrect.  He did mention he wants to ultimately use PyCrypto on GAE, but this particular question is about not being able to install and run PyCrypto on a Windows machine

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any of this, just [install from the PyCrypto binaries](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml)

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, simply download and install [ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win64-x64.msi](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.7.2.5/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win64-x64.msi) (*or* [ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.7.2.5/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi) for Win32) then run **pypm install pycrypto**

Comment: Don't listen to this guy, when you do this, it will error saying you need a 'business subscription' to it to run this command, then it will make you do the whole get a quote / jerk off thing and then it probably won't work afterwards.